# Recent question considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently posted this question, which was flagged as off-topic:

[How to approach the stigma of not having a math degree?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196026/how-to-approach-the-stigma-of-not-having-a-math-degree)

I'm not sure why it was flagged. MO asks for questions about research-level mathematics. The question is about how to better engage in research-level mathematics. I also know a number of folks who share similar concerns / would be interested in getting some insights from the math research crowd.

Is there a way I can modify the question to better meet the criteria of MO? Or would it be better to repost on academia.stackexchange?

Comment: I think questions of this type are better suited for academia.SE.

Comment: My guess is that it will also be closed on academia.SE, but I'm not particularly active there so I could be wrong.  But it's not an appropriate question for MO.  The reasons for this were amply covered in the comments on the original question.

Comment: wasn't a mathematics question. It was asking personal advice from someone unwilling to use a real name.

Comment: @WillJagy  Especially in such a case this seems really odd to reproach this. Can't you imagine that it might be just a bit worrying to complain about interactions with other mathematicians in a public forum read by many mathematicians using ones real name. I mean there will only be that many colleagues that will have   interacted with the person behind that user.  IIRC, there were even cases were regular users of the site created a dedicated anon account just to ask such types of questions.

Comment: I suggest that, if a question, comment, answer, absolutely requires anonymity as a prerequisite for public posting, then maybe MO is not the best place for it. Some interpersonal problems have no good solution; I would love certain experts to answer my questions in quadratic forms, in particular continue to reply to email from me; questions I have not even put on MO because of the huge quantity of background required. I don't create extra identities and tell them to be nice to Will Jagy. I don't know how else to put this.

Comment: Where was I; I also don't create extra identities to ask various third parties how to get those experts to be nice to the person behind the identity. Sigh.

Comment: Well, in case I don't delete these, the experts I mention have answered my questions in the past, very well; I just always have new questions.

Comment: @quid, left you some stuff, I think I will leave it in place for a bit.

Comment: @WillJagy thank you I saw it. I agree that the question is not a great fit for the site.  Only, the precise objection felt a bit strange to me. I hope you will find the answers you seek one way or another.